# XamDataGrid Allow Field Chooser but not Data Source selection

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

[image]

In short I want to remove that combo box from my field chooser but I can't figure out what property to enable or disable.

I haven't been able to find this referenced in the documentation anywhere.

It doesn't seem to do it when I build the columns in XAML but I am returning my display columns from a database so I need to build them dynamically in my View behind code.

The closest thing I found was this

```
FieldLayouts[0].Settings.RecordSelectorLocation = RecordSelectorLocation.None;
```

But this makes the field chooser disappear which is clearly not what I want.

## Update

I have also tried attaching to the FieldChooserOpening event and modifying its contents from here but I haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public Constructor()
    {
        this.FieldChooserOpening += thisObject_FieldChooserOpening;
    }

    void thisObject_FieldChooserOpening(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Events.FieldChooserOpeningEventArgs e)
    {
        e.FieldChooser.FieldGroupSelectorVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```